# I'm always getting 301 HTTP header code even if the site doesn't exist (PHP)

Tags: php, http, instagram

I'm trying to figure out if a Instagram User exists or not. If the user site doesn't exist, it should give me a '404 Not Found' in the headers, but i'm always getting a '301 Moved Permanently', even if the user doesn't exist! 
My browser gives me a 404:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LUFK.png
Can u help me? This is my code:

```php
<?php 
$url = "https://www.instagram.com/asdsdfsvxd"; //This user doesn't exist
echo $url;
$file_headers = @get_headers($url);
echo $file_headers[0];
if($file_headers[0] !== 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
  echo "exists";
} else {
  echo "not exists";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

Dont forget the trailing `/` (slash).

`$url = "https://www.instagram.com/asdsdfsvxd/";`

**Output:**

```
$ php test.php
https://www.instagram.com/asdsdfsvxd/HTTP/1.1 404 Not Foundnot exists
```

Comment: I know. I know.